# In c++, how can i display all numbers of a linear series?

Tags: c++

This is what i have so far. I can display the first, second, and last numbers of the series.

```
int main()
{   
  int a,b,c;
  cout<<"The first number: "<<endl;
  cin>>a;
  cout<<"The difference: "<<endl;
  cin>>b;
  cout<<"How many numbers are in the series: "<<endl;
  cin>>c;

  cout<<"The numbers of the linear series are: "<<endl;
  cout<<a<<endl; 
  cout<<a+b<<endl; cout<<a+b*(c-1)<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I tried the 'for' cycle, but i have the same problem; i can't display c amount of numbers, becouse then i would have to make

```
cout<<a+b; cout<<a+b*2; cout<<a+b*3;
```

and so on. And this wouldn't even make sense if the series only had 2 elements.

How can i show the numbers between the first and last numbers of the linear series? Does it have to do something with 'string'? Also, is there a way to do something like

```
cout<<a*1,a*2,a*3...a*n;
```

**I know that this code doesn't make sense, but hopefully you get the idea**

Comment: put `cout` inside `for`

Comment: Hint: `cout << (a + b*i)`.

Comment: Why the `basic` tag?  What does your question have to do with the BASIC language?

Comment: Your code do makes sense. Just tiny little things are missing. A hint a provided abobe by @zwol. You can surely follow it and use it with a for loop. Good going. Give it a little more effort and then you will see the magic.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews They probably thought its reserved for beginner's _basic_ questions. What a pity, its not.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He might have thought of it as Programming basic's basic.

Comment: If the hint from @zwol doesn't get you there, then I'd suggest reading up more on the for loop, you're so close, and have touched all the right things, it's just how to put it together!

Comment: First time here, i thought "basic" means beginner. @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 1):

When constructing linear sequences all numbers are of the form `f(n) = a + b*n`, you can put this to your advantage using a `for` loop as you mention that you have tried.  You should be able to figure it out from the following pseudocode:

```
Output "The numbers of the linear series are: "
For i = 0 to c-1
    Output a + b*i
Next i
```